# Working with files in Expect

Tags: linux, expect

I want to read a file contents, do some processing and write them to another file by using `Expect` scripting tool.

Let's assume that I have File_A contains the following data:

```
The IP address of this machine is: "0.0.0.0"
```

I want to read the contents of File_A, modify them and write them to File_B, which should be like the following:

```
The IP address of this machine is: "192.168.0.69"
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `Expect` is an extension of `Tcl`. Have a look at [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/367) to know about how to read/write with `Tcl` and [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sed command to replace file content as below.Then use move command to make backup file as you want.

```
sed -i.bk  's/0.0.0.0/192.168.0.69/g' File_A.txt
mv File_A.txt.bk File_B.txt
```

Explanation:

sed = Stream EDitor
-i = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file)
The command string:

s = the substitute command

0.0.0.0 = a regular expression describing the word to replace (or just the word itself)

192.168.0.69 = the text to replace it with

g = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurred

Comment: Thats really perfect and easy command, and its what I am really looking for. Thank you so much @Kasun.